# Informatica PowerCenter Workflow - Flat File Path in Workflow Session, on Windows Machine

Tags: informatica

I have created a simple mapping to convert file from one format to another. Power Center 9.5.1 client  is running on Windows machine. I am NOT able to set full "Source filename" correctly in Workflow Session.

1. When I set it to ""c:\temp\people.csv", somehow slashes get converted to backslashes, resulting in file reading error.  "READER_1_1_1    FR_3000 Error opening file ["c:/temp/people.csv"]."
2. I tried URL format ""file:\c:\temp\people.csv", but it did not work either. Also "c:/temp/people.csv" does not work.
3. Please note, I tried using both "Source file directory" and "Source filename", but slash conversion still takes place, resulting in error.

Any suggestions? IS there any setting to keep paths as is, windows style. TIA

Comment: I assume your informatica server in Windows box so this is strange. How does your session log location showing in your session log? if that's correct, then there is some issue with target file location. But if your server is in UNIX this is expected and normal.

Comment: Try providing the file in back slash c:/temp/people.csv

Comment: I had tried with "c:/temp/people.csv" too, but it did not work. I will update question.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the slash issue. It seems you're refering to local path, where your Informatica Client is installed. Please note, mappings get executed on Informatica Integration Service and you need to point to a path accessible by the server.